# Proof of uniform continuity of a continuous function on an interval [a,b] without using compactness arguments

Tags: uniform-continuity

I give a proof of mine of the fact that if $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, then it is uniformly continuous. The idea is to avoid using compactness arguments (with coverings), but prove it in a direct way.

Proof: Let $\epsilon>0$, which is kept fixed. For each $x\in [a,b]$ we define the set:

$$A(x)=\{\delta\in(0,1] : \lvert y-x\rvert<\delta \Rightarrow\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert<\epsilon\}.$$

Every $A(x)$ is non-empty, because $f$ is continuous at $x$ and is clearly bounded above by $1$.

Therefore $\sup A(x)$ exists for all $x\in [a,b]$. We label

$$E(x)=\sup A(x),$$
$$\Delta=\inf\{E(x) : x\in [a,b]\}.$$

Our goal is to show that $\Delta>0$.

There is obviously a sequence such that $x_{i} \in [a,b]$ and such that $E(x_{i})\rightarrow\Delta$. There is also a subsequence (we don't change indices) such that $x_{i}\rightarrow\bar{x}\in[a,b]$. Let $\bar{\delta}=\sup A(\bar{x})$.

We define for each $c>0$ such that $0<c<\epsilon$, the set:

$$A(c)=\{\delta\in(0,1]:\lvert y-\bar{x}\rvert<\delta\Rightarrow\lvert f(y)-f(\bar{x})\rvert<\epsilon-c\}$$

and $\delta(c)=\sup A(c)$.

We will show that ${\displaystyle \lim_{c \to 0^{+}}}\delta(c)=\bar{\delta}$.

Indeed, we first observe that $\delta(c)\leq\bar{\delta}$ for every $c$ with $0<c<\epsilon$. (Because $\lvert f(y)-f(\bar{x})\rvert<\epsilon-c<\epsilon$).

Therefore $A(c)\subseteq A(\bar{x})$. Let $c_{n}\to 0^{+}$. Then, if for each $q<\bar{\delta}$ there only finite $n$ such that $\delta(c_{n})<q<\bar{\delta}$ then we have the definition of $\delta(c)\rightarrow\bar{\delta}$.

Now assume there is an infinity of $n$ for which $\delta(c_{n})<q<\bar{\delta}$.

Then for each $y$ with $\lvert y-\bar{x}\rvert <q<\delta$ we have $\lvert f(y)-f(x)\rvert<\epsilon$.

Now if there is one $n$ of this infinity of $n$ such that, for $y$ with $\lvert y-\bar{x}\rvert<q$ we have $\lvert f(y)-f(\bar{x})\rvert<\epsilon-c_{n}$, then $q\in A(c_{n})$ hence $q\leq\delta(c_{n})$, contradiction! Thus for each $n$ of the infinity there is an $y_{n}$ with $\lvert y_{n}-\bar{x}\rvert<q$ and $\lvert f(y_{n})-f(\bar{x})\rvert\geq\epsilon-c_{n}$'

Taking a subsequence (we don't change indices) $y_{n}\rightarrow y_{0}$ we get $\lvert y_{0}-\bar{x}\rvert\leq q$ and $\lvert f(y_{0})-f(\bar{x})\rvert\geq\epsilon$.

But $\lvert y_{0}-\bar{x}\rvert\leq q<\bar{\delta} $ implies $\lvert f(y_{0})-f(\bar{x})\rvert<\epsilon$, contradiction.

Therefore, $\delta(c_{n})\rightarrow\bar{\delta}$ and clearly there is a $c_{0}\in(0,\epsilon)$ with $\delta(c_{0})>\dfrac{\bar{\delta}}{2}$.

For the sequence $x_{i}$ and for large $i$'s (since $x_{i}\rightarrow\bar{x}$) we get $\lvert x_{i}-\bar{x}\rvert<\dfrac{\bar{\delta}}{2}$ and $\lvert f(x_{i})-f(\bar{x})\rvert<c_{0}$.

Let $y$ be such that $\lvert y-x_{i}\rvert<\delta(c_{0})-\dfrac{\bar{\delta}}{2}$.

Then $\lvert y-x_{i}\rvert+\lvert x_{i}-\bar{x}\rvert<\delta(c_{0})$ hence $\lvert y-\bar{x}\rvert<\delta(c_{0})$ which implies $\lvert f(y)-f(\bar{x})\rvert<\epsilon-c_{0}$. But $\lvert f(x_{i})-f(\bar{x})\rvert<c_{0}$

and hence $\lvert f(y)-f(x_{i})\rvert<\epsilon$.

We have shown that $\lvert y-x_{i}\lvert<\delta(c_{0})-\dfrac{\bar{\delta}}{2}\Rightarrow \lvert f(y)-f(x_{i})\rvert<\epsilon$, therefore $\delta(c_{0})-\dfrac{\bar{\delta}}{2}\in A(x_{i})$ for large $i$. Hence $E(x_{i})\geq\delta(c_{0})-\dfrac{\bar{\delta}}{2}$ for $i$ greater than a certain $i_{0}$.

Therefore $\inf\{E(x): x\in [a,b]\}=\lim E(x_{i})\geq\delta(c_{0})-\dfrac{\bar{\delta}}{2}>0$, that is $\Delta>0$.

Cosequently $E(x)\geq\Delta>0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.

So taking a $\delta >0$ such that $\delta<\Delta$ we obtain:

$\lvert y-x\rvert<\delta\Rightarrow\lvert y-x\rvert<\Delta\leq E(x)$. Since $E(x)=\sup A(x)$ there is a $\tilde{\delta}$ arbitrarily close to $E(x)$, hence $\tilde{\delta}\in A(x)$ and $\tilde{\delta}>\delta$, therefore $\lvert y-x\rvert<\delta<\tilde{\delta}$ and hence $\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert<\epsilon$.

So there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $\lvert x-y\rvert<\delta \Rightarrow \lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert<\epsilon$, and since $\epsilon$ was arbitrarily chosen in the first place we have proved uniform continuity!

I will be deeply obliged to anyone who reads this long proof, and I would be indebted if he finds some errors or he has a simpler proof to propose!

Comment: May I ask why you are so interested in a direct proof?

Comment: As I read this, you are interested in a proof that is (1) direct; (2) does not involve open coverings (Heine-Borel theorem); and (3)  is different and/or simpler than what you posted.  The given answers really don't provide what you want if I am not mistaken. I can provide that if you are interested.

Comment: I think that my original answer is correct, but it was proposed to me another much shorter and simpler proof which is the proof by  Abhijeet Vats not in its original form but as it was altered in the comments we made! I think it is short, correct and complete. But if you have a better or simpler, please do post it, by all means!

Comment: @GeorgeTsoutsinos:  See this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/894726/148510).

Comment: It is correct but it follows exactly the same logic of my original proof! The proof with sequences I think it is shorter and simpler. Assume that uniform continuity does not hold. Then there is an $\epsilon>0$ and sequences $x_{n},y_{n}$ such that $|x_{n}-y_{n}|<1/n$ and $|f(x_{n})-f(y_{n}|\geq\,\epsilon$. Since $x_{n}$ is in $[a,b]$ there is a subsequence $x_{n_{k}}\,\to \bar{x}$. Take the same indices for $y_{n_{k}}$. Then $|x_{n_{k}}-y_{n_{k}}|<1/n_{k}$ which implies $y_{n_{k}}\to \bar{x}$ and $|f(x_{n_{k}})-f(y_{n_{k}})|$$\geq\epsilon$ giving $0\geq\epsilon$ , contradiction!

Answer (score 1):

You are actually using compactness when you choose a convergent subsequence $x_i \to \overline{x}$. But if you are happy with that kind of argument, then this can be shortened significantly: Assume that $f$ is not uniformly continuous. Then there is an $\varepsilon > 0$ and two sequences $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}},(y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $[a,b]$ such that $|x_n-y_n| < \frac{1}{n}$ and $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)| \geq \varepsilon$. By taking subsequences, we may assume that $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to y$. In fact, $x = y$ because $|x_n-y_n| < \frac{1}{n}$. It follows
$$0 = |f(x)-f(y)| = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} |f(x_n)-f(y_n)| \geq \varepsilon,$$
where we used the continuity of $f$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Let me provide the standard proof.

Assume that $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is not uniformly continuous. Then:
$$\exists \epsilon > 0: \forall \delta >0:\exists x,y \in [a,b]:|x-y|<\delta \land |f(x)-f(y)| \geq \epsilon$$

In other words:
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \exists x_n, y_n \in [a,b]: |x_n-y_n| < \frac{1}{n} \land |f(x_n)-f(y_n)| \geq \epsilon$$
This actually allows us to form two sequences $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. Now, I will leave it to you to try and determine why these two sequences can be assumed to be convergent (Hint: Bolzano-Weierstrass helps you over here). Let the limits of each of these sequences be $x$ and $y$. Then:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} |x-y| \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} |x-x_n| + \lim_{n \to \infty} |x_n-y_n| + \lim_{n \to \infty} |y_n-y| = 0$$
I've purposely skipped steps here so you can fill in some of the details on your own. But this implies that $x = y$. On the other hand, the continuity of $f$ at $x$ entails that:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} |f(x_n)-f(y_n)| = 0 \geq \epsilon$$
and this is a contradiction. Hence, $f$ must be uniformly continuous. $\Box$

Now, it's strange that you classify a compactness argument as being "indirect". Actually, the compactness argument is direct! Indeed, Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. For each $x \in [a,b]$, we can find a $\delta_x$ such that:
$$y \in B(x,\delta_x) \implies f(y) \in B(f(x),\epsilon)$$
In other words, $f(B(x,\delta_x)) \subseteq B(f(x),\epsilon)$. It follows that $\{B(x,\frac{1}{2}\delta_x)\}_{x \in X}$ is an open cover for $[a,b]$. But this means that we can find finitely many points $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ such that $\{B(x_i,\frac{1}{2}\delta_{x_i})\}_{i=1}^{n}$ is a finite subcover of $[a,b]$. Next, choose $\delta = \min \frac{1}{2} \delta_i$ and let $|x-y| < \delta$. Observe that $x \in B(x_i,\frac{1}{2}\delta_{x_i})$. But this means that:
$$|y-x_i| \leq |y-x| + |x-x_i| < \frac{1}{2}\delta_{x_i} +\frac{1}{2}\delta_{x_i} = \delta_{x_i}$$

So, $y \in B(x_i,\delta_{x_i})$. But that means that:
$$|f(x)-f(y)| \leq |f(x)-f(x_i)| +|f(x_i)-f(y)| < 2\epsilon$$
and that shows what we wanted. This is direct! $\Box$

I actually wanted to make two remarks on the first proof:

1. In that proof, it may not look like it but you are actually making use of a compactness principle. Indeed, the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem is a compactness principle on the real line. It's just that it has more to do with sequential compactness.
2. In the moment where I formed those two sequences, I actually did make use of the axiom of choice. The proof there actually isn't constructive; I haven't given a direct, explicit way to find those two sequences. The compactness argument (via open covers) circumvents this. Having said that, my favorite argument is actually the sequential one because it is very simple.

Comment: Thank you my friend! I just came back from the sea, so give me some time to have a better look at it! I wish your proof to be correct because I will avoid all the long and tedious arguments of my proof! The other proof (with coverings) is well known but I am not allowed to use such arguments in my notes. All I am allowed to assume is that a bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence!

Comment: It seems OK! Thanks a lot! I upvote!

Comment: Hmm, given what you've written, I actually do want to make a slight edit to my post. But if you did like the answer, then maybe consider accepting it? :D I'll make the edit now and you can have a look at it in a bit.

Comment: I don't see any need for edit, but please do!

Comment: I have already upvoted it!

Comment: I suspect what the problem may be! That the subsequences we obtain $x_{n_{k}}$ and $y_{n_{m}}$ do not necessarily have the same indices! For example we may have ${x_{2}, x_{4},......}$ and ${y_{1},y_{3},y_{5},....}$. How do we solve this problem?

Comment: Right, so take $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. This is a bounded sequence so we can find a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$. Now, consider $(y_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$. This is a bounded sequence so we can find a convergent subsequence $(y_{n_{k_m}})_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$. Then, notice that $(x_{n_{k_m}})_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ is convergent too. In other words, we can just take these two subsequences and they both work.

Comment: OK it seems that it works!

Comment: Yea so earlier, I actually meant that you should upvote my answer if it was helpful for you. There's a tick that you can click beside my answer.

Comment: I already did a long time ago!